# Combine to def functions to one in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have coded a funktion to calculate the mean square displacement MSD  and the velocity auto correlation function VACF for a lennard Jones Fluid ... but for both MSD and VACF are there to funktion one to calculate that calculates the value and one that runs the other for a list of numbers and saves it to a new list ...
And i am searching for a way to combine the to so that I just have one funktion for MSD and one for VACF

MSC funktions:

```
def calculate_MSD(R_1, R_2, n_particles):
  MSD = 0
  for a in range(n_particles):
    MSD += np.dot(((R_2)[:,a] - (R_1)[:,a]),((R_2)[:,a] - (R_1)[:,a]))
  MSD /= n_particles
  return MSD

def cal_MSD_list(R_list_eq):
  MSD_total_list =[]
  for t in range(len(R_list_eq)):
    MSD = calculate_MSD(R_list_eq[0], R_list_eq[t], n_particles)
    MSD_total_list.append(MSD)
  return MSD_total_list
```

VACF funktions:

```
def calculate_VACF(V_1, V_2, n_particles):
  VACF = 0
  for a in range(n_particles):
    VACF += np.dot(((V_2)[:,a]), ((V_1)[:,a]))
  VACF /= n_particles
  return VACF

def cal_VACF_list(V_list_eq):
  VACF_total_list =[]
  for t in range(len(V_list_eq)):
    VACF = calculate_VACF(V_list_eq[0], V_list_eq[t], n_particles)
    VACF_total_list.append(VACF)
  return VACF_total_list
```

Answer (score 1):

The way it is implemented right now is much better as it has divided functionalities into different functions. But still if you want to divide into a single function, you can do as follows:

```
def cal_MSD_list(R_list_eq):
  MSD_total_list =[]
  for t in range(len(R_list_eq)):
    MSD = 0
    for a in range(n_particles):
      MSD += np.dot(((R_list_eq[t])[:,a] - (R_list_eq[0])[:,a]),((R_list_eq[t])[:,a] - (R_list_eq[0])[:,a]))
      MSD /= n_particles
    MSD_total_list.append(MSD)
  return MSD_total_list
```

Same thing can be done for the second one too. I think that this might help your purpose. Feel free to comment if any problem arises.